# Where should I put this javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Ok I have this problem for hours now. I have a `select` tag from html and its option is populated by php like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="statusOption" id="status">
    <?php
       $connn = $dbObject->dbConnect();
       $results = $connn->query("SELECT statusName from status");
       $counter=0;
       while($statusNames = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
       {
          if($dbObject->getStatusValue($idstatus[0])===$statusNames[0])
             echo "<option selected='selected' value='".$counter."''>".$statusNames[0]."</option>";
          else echo "<option value='".$counter."''>".$statusNames[0]."</option>";
          $counter++;
       }
       $connn->close();

...... etc
```

The point here is, that select tag is inside a modal. Now by default, the select tag is selected base from the database (The button here is "edit the status" so example I have "working" status, When I click the edit button, the modal shows up, and the select tag automatically selects "working". The same thing also with "Defect". Now for error trapping purposes, if by default the select tag selects working, If I change the option to "defect", another select tag should pop out (It's for the status remarks like repair,replace, or disposal). And If I change the option of the select tag again to "Working" the select tag of remarks should be gone because it is only for the "defect" thing.

The problem is this. I have this code (javascript) so that I can manipulate that showing and hiding of that other select tag:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#status').change(function(){
                if($(this).val() === 1){
                    $('#hide').show();
                }else{
                    $('#hide').hide();
                }
            });
            </script>
```

The ID of the select tag of status is status and then the select tag for the remarks is hide:

```
<select class="form-control" name="statusRemark" style="display: none;" id="hide">
 <?php 
     $connn = $dbObject->dbConnect();
     $results = $connn->query("SELECT statusremarkName from statusremark");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
     {
        echo "<option>".$row[0]."</option>";
     }
      $connn->close();

  ?>
  </select>
```

However. When I put my Script tag in the head tag of html or in the bottom of the body tag or in after the select tag, none of it is working. Even echoing it in php, that doesn't help. I don't know where to put that script in order for the other select tag to show up when I click Defect. Help?

Comment: Ok if youre confuse who's the "1" in the `$(this).val() === 1` As you can see from the select id=status , i counter it using php assuming 0 is working and then 1 is the Defect

Comment: It just has to be anywhere after the element it's targeting (the `<select class="form-control" name="statusOption" id="status">` in this case).  Or, more specifically, it needs to be executed after that element exists.  What is the actual HTML when this problem occurs?  Can you provide a minimal and complete example of HTML/JavaScript where this "doesn't work"?

Comment: have you tried wrapping your jquery in a document ready function? that will ensure the dom has rendered before attempting to attach an event to it

Comment: @David Should I echo it in php or put a script after the `<select class="form-control" name="statusOption" id="status">` tag?

Comment: You did not use id on select. I think thats the problem. And while using jquery with dynamic content i suggest following $(document).on('event','element',function){}

Comment: @pinoyvendetta: Whichever you prefer, really.  They both accomplish the same thing.  Client-side code has no knowledge of and doesn't care anything about PHP.

Comment: Have you added reference to `jquery,js` file? Are there any console errors?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes I have jquery js file at the very top of my php file. no I dont have console errors. seems strange.

Comment: Try with `$(document).on('change','#status',function(){...});`

Comment: Like this?
`<script type='text/javascript'> 
            $(document).on('event','element',function){
                $('#status').change(function(){
                    if($(this).val() === 1){
                        $('#hide').show();
                    }else{
                        $('#hide').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
                </script>` @GuruprasadRao

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: not like that.. `$(document).on('change','#status',function(){if($(this).val() === 1){ $('#hide').show(); }else{ $('#hide').hide(); }});`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao nothing happens in the modal

Comment: Try `$(this).val() === "1"`. I don't think your `if` condition is satisfying at all..

Comment: Yea I just found it just now too. putting "" in 1 also triggers the other select tag now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW THE ANSWER IS SIMPLE. I use @D Lowther 's code and then tweak a little bit. This line of code `if($(this).val() === 1){` I change it to `if($(this).val() == 1){` I don't know how but. pretty strange why that small makes a big headache.

EDIT: okay as what @Guruprasad Rao is suggesting `if($(this).val() === "1"` Also works.

Answer (score 1):

adding to illustrate my comment from above.  As for where to add it, I suggest at the bottom of the body element. The issue you are having is not related to your php, unless you are mismatching the selectors as you dynamically create them before loading to the client. My guess is that either the event isn't properly attaching because it is running before the document has fully loaded and not finding your content, or you are trying to select on an incorrect selector. Someone else suggested event delegation, which also might work to solve the firing before dom render issue.

```
<script>
    // Adding the jQuery namespace and aliasing, this avoids namespace 
    // collision in codebases that have multiple handlers running jquery 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#status').on('change', function(event){
            // adding a log here for debugging, will make sure 
            // you are triggering the event even if you see no change
            console.log('inside change handler');
            console.log($(this).val());

            if($(this).val() === 1){
                $('#hide').show();
            }else{
                $('#hide').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried your code. as what ive expected i got 0 from working and 1 from defect. But the other select tag doesnt show up.